# How to deal with no values in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

Recently I've been working on cable position/height approximation using canny and contours. When no area found in roi, it will print out text that says "error". But when I do `elif area < 0:` then print out some text, area of contours return nothing / no value is printed in terminal, so the "error" text is not shown. Basically, when the cable is out of roi, it will show text says "error" but area returns no value at the beginning when it's out of roi. How to deal with this kind of problem?

```
for c in contours:
    area = cv.contourArea(c)
    print(area)
    if area > 3100 and area <10000:
        #drawcontour = cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
        x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(c)
        center_of_rect = ((x + x + w)/2, (y + y + h)/2)
        cv.circle(img, (int(center_of_rect[0]),int(center_of_rect[1])), 5, (0,255,255),-1)
        words = f"approx position = {center_of_rect[1]}"
        #print(int(center_of_rect[1])) 
        rect = cv.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255),2)
        cv.putText(img, words, (x,y-5), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 1)
    elif area < 0:
        cv.putText(img, "Error", (20,50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

I've tried `elif area is None:` and it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Before using area you need to check if it exists (else, print an error):

```
for c in contours:
    area = cv.contourArea(c)
    if area:
        print(area)
        if area > 3100 and area <10000:
            #drawcontour = cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
            x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(c)
            center_of_rect = ((x + x + w)/2, (y + y + h)/2)
            cv.circle(img, (int(center_of_rect[0]),int(center_of_rect[1])), 5, (0,255,255),-1)
            words = f"approx position = {center_of_rect[1]}"
            #print(int(center_of_rect[1])) 
            rect = cv.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255),2)
            cv.putText(img, words, (x,y-5), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 1)
        elif area < 0:
            cv.putText(img, "Error", (20,50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2)
    else:
        cv.putText(img, "Error", (20,50), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2)
```

Comment: it still not print out anything in the screen. but after the cable go into the roi and go out again, then its massage appear.